# Deleting Hive Staging Directory for a running Spark JOB

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hadoop2

What will happen if for a running Spark JOB another process deletes .hiveStaging directory?

1. Will it cause JOB Failure
2. Data Loss but JOB Success
3. Not Data loss and JOB Success

Or, are there any HDFS locks that will cause the Directory to be not getting deleted

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hive uses temporary folders both on the machine running the Hive client and the default HDFS instance. These folders are used to store per-query temporary/intermediate data sets and are normally cleaned up by the hive client when the query is finished.

Once, the query execution completes the data is moved to the output HDFS location.

When you delete the `.hiveStaging` directory your hive query/driver code will fail with `java.io.IOException`.